# Apache Spark Streaming is Not Reading the Directory

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark

I'm working on Spark Streaming and I want to set a local directory to stream data to my spark application such that every new text file on that directory will be streamed to my application. I tried using `StreamingContext`'s `textFileStream` method but I haven't gotten any data from files I've moved to my specified local directory. Could you help me to find why this is happening?

So here is the code I've written:

```
def main():

    if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print 'Usage: SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit CoinpipeVectorBuilder.py <SPARK_HOME> <dir_streaming> ' \
          '<dir_crawled_addresses> <dir_output_vectors>'
    sys.exit(1)

    #Set the path to crawled outputs according to the parameter passed to the spark script
    global path_crawled_output
    path_crawled_output = sys.argv[4]

    global sc, ssc
    sconf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")\
        .setAppName("CoinPipeVectorBuilder")\
        .set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=sconf)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
    tx_and_addr_stream = ssc.textFileStream(sys.argv[2])

    tx_and_addr_stream.foreachRDD(parseAndBuildVectors)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So inside the parseAndBuildVectors I get no data even if I move a new file to the specified directory I had passed to `ssc.textFileStream`

Comment: I created a dir with `hadoop fs -mkdir <path>` and used this dir as my testFileStream and it worked.

Comment: This is very late response but by default it's reading from HDFS.  In order to read from the local file system you have to use `file:` prefix. e.g.  `file:/usr/lib/spark/docs/_site/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

Spark code execute on work. So work have not any access for your local file system. This is not possible directly. You can read stream file then make RDD Then can perform operation using spark. Spark can access only distributed data.